# No network utilization Google Chrome task manager, but Microsoft Windows Resource Monitor disagrees

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome

According to Google Chrome task manager, Chrome doesn't use any network:

[image]

However,  Microsoft Windows Resource Monitor shows that Google Chrome uses around 100 kilobytes per second symmetric:

[image]

[image]

What could explain the discrepancy between Google Chrome task manager and Microsoft Windows Resource Monitor regarding the network utilization?

Note that the upload from Google Chrome has consistently been between 50 and 150 kilobytes per second for over one hour:

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate with latest version of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short, this is apparently a (longstanding) bug in Chrome.**

From what I surmise, the Chrome Task Manager only updates its network utilization upon download completion, but should do it continuously:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1010880

(While this is a Chromium bug tracker, the issue actually specifies official Chrome build, across OSs.)  I would say we should file a bug report, but it's been done...

I'm only reviving this ancient thread since this is the first hit when Googling the result, and it is *still* a problem.  I just replicated the issue on Windows 10 x64 and Chrome (Version 118.0.5993.118 (Official Build) (64-bit)).  I'm streaming video from a Ubiquiti NVM in Chrome: Windows Task Manager reports ~4 Mbps network utilization, but Chrome Task Manager reports nothing.